# How to get the blue style text in 2.1 Contacts or Preferences

Tags: android, coding-style, android-layout

Running Android 2.1, preferences and other dialogs have white/blue text.  Looking at theme values I see things like textColorPrimary and textColorSecondary.  If I reference those colors in my layout xml, with something like:

```
  android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorSecondary"
```

I just see white text (I have tried textColorPrimary, textColorTertiary and textColorHint also).

I do not have any theme values stated in my manifest file.  I am presuming this means I am using the system default theme.

All that said, am I barking up the wrong tree with textColor* references?

Answer (score 1):

all the textColor* attributes point to [color selectors](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/ColorStateList.html).
If you want to change the color for your theme you need to perform the following steps:

1) Create a color selector, create a file named (for example) primary_color.xml and put it under res\color folder

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="@android:color/bright_foreground_light_disabled"/>
    <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:color="@android:color/bright_foreground_light"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@android:color/bright_foreground_light"/>
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="@android:color/bright_foreground_light"/>
    <item android:color="@android:color/bright_foreground_light"/> <!-- not selected -->
```

2) In your styles.xml file, create a theme for your activity that references your newly created color selector:

```
<style name="ActivityStyle" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/primary_color</item>
        <!-- Add more styles here as necessary -->
</style>
```

3) In your AndroidManifest.xml, apply the new theme to any activity you want:

```
<activity android:name=".activities.MedicationsActivity"
       android:theme="@style/ActivityStyle">
 </activity>
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment Lior.  But what I am really after is quite the opposite.  I want to use the existing theme color.  I have hard coded a blue color which matches the blue used by settings and contacts, but want to use a soft theme reference.