# Setting text as "primary" in Android

Tags: android, coding-style, themes, textview

While looking through the built in Android themes/styles I noticed references to textColorPrimary, textColorSecondary etc. I would like to implement this in to my own theme but cannot find any way of setting a textview (or any view) to "primary" or "secondary" etc.

Am I overlooking something or is it not possible to be done?

Comment: Does this post help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4440967/how-to-get-the-blue-style-text-in-2-1-contacts-or-preferences

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The references you're seeing to "textColor_____" are references to color selectors. You use them with a line like 'android:textColor="?android:textColorSecondary"' in the xml definition of your TextView.

See this for more detail:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html#ReferencesToThemeAttributes

Comment: That looks like what I am after! :D Just trying it out now. Thanks!